# Decoding Google 2 Factor Authentication QR Code Format

Tags: qr-code, two-factor-authentication

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator), google 2 factor authentication secret key is supposed to be a 16 character base32 string. When I decode the QR Code that google sent me, I find that it complies with the [Key format specified by google](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format), but I find that the secret length is not right. Has google changed the secret length or encoding format? Is there any way for me to get the 16 character base32 string from the secret key I have? My key from the QR code (which I obviously am not copying and pasting exactly) is:

```
otpauth://totp/Google%3Amyemail%40gmail.com?secret=7gmdmzctmhpm7i6nrmbom6u5gny7o6la&issuer=Google
```

Here's what I know:

1. It isn't hex.
2. It is 32 characters long.
3. It does comply with base32, but why is it all lower case? The example on [google's key format specification](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format) showed it all uppercase?

The only thing I can imagine is that google has changed the format from only 16 characters to 32 characters. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1):

The length of the secret is only 16 characters which are all one case.

It doesn't matter if it is a lowercase *a* or uppercase *A* as it translates into the same bit.

Answer (score 0):

It is a a 16, 26 or 32 character base32 string. See, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.